# SQL CE parameter passing

Tags: sql, parameters, windows-ce

I have a number of queries which are checking for a record in a table and if there is no such a record it is added. There are 2 queries involved in this process:

1) `select id from table where <conditions>`

if there is any ids corresponding to  I do nothing(or update records with ids as I want), if there are no ids I executing second query:

2) `insert into table(<columns>) values(<values>)`

Of course `<conditions>`, `<columns>` and `<values>` are correct strings for their context.
What I want is to join these 2 queries into one:

`insert into table(<values>)
select <parameter list>
where not exists(select id from table where <conditions>)`

So there will be only one query involved instead of 2.
The example of this query is:

`insert into persons(name) select @Name where not exists (select id from persons where name = @Name)`

The problem is that I use parameters for queries and when I execute this composite query I get an exception saying "A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement." 
Is there a way to bypass parameters and don't get an exception for this query? 
I'm using C# and SqlCe-related classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the benefit of merging the queries into a composite?  If the query is supported (and I actually doubt that the SQL Compact Query Parser supports this) the sql engine is still going to have to essentially do both queries anyway.  I find the two separate queries more readable.

As separate queries, I'm also willing to bet you could make it substantially faster than the composite query anyway by using TableDirect.  Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161892/update-insert-to-a-table-using-sqlceresultset/3162168#3162168) and benchmark it in your app.  It's likely 10x faster than your existing query pair becasue it foregoes the query parser altogether.

Comment: There are dozens or hundreds of such queries, by compositing them I can at least shorten the code. And I'll definitely give a try for TableDirect, never used it before

Comment: While I'm a huge fan of decreasing LOC, shorter but less readable code is not necessarily a win.  And be careful with TableDirect.  Once you use it, you may never want to write another SQL query again.